# How do I shift a WordPress block to the left on mobile devices only?

Tags: css

I'm new to this. I'm having difficulty getting a specific content block (latest posts) in WordPress to be further left on mobile devices with less padding or margin.

In the additional CSS classes spot on the content block I added the class `.latestposts`.

Then in the additional CSS for the site customization, I added:

```
@media all (max-width: 700px) {
   .latestposts {
      margin-left: -15%;
      padding-left:0;
   }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to be doing anything. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Below query should target : On screens that are 700px or less

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
 .latestposts {
      margin-left: -15%;
      padding-left:0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Strange! It's still not causing any change when published and the site is viewed on a mobile device.

Comment: I also have this in there, which does seem to be working (but just for changing the font size, as I intend): @media (max-width: 700px) {
    blockquote {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    li {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
 
}